# How to manage concurrency in querys?

Tags: python, django, database, transactions, django-rest-framework

I have this code:

```py
if LikedSlot.objects.filter(restaurant__id=r.id, user__id=u.id).count() == 0:
    l = LikedSlot.objects.create(restaurant=r, user=u)
```

So the idea is to create a new LikedSlot only if the user didn't liked the restaurant before, but I have a race condition because two requests can get `True` in the first line if it's reached at the same time.

I tried the following but it doesn't seem to fix the issue either:

```py
from django.db import transaction

with transaction.atomic():
    if LikedSlot.objects.filter(restaurant__id=r.id, user__id=u.id).count() == 0:
        l = LikedSlot.objects.create(restaurant=r, user=u)
```

Do you have an idea how to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you to use your database's referential integrity in such cases. Change your model so that the resturant+user pair is unique:

```
class LikedSlot(models.Model):
    ...
    class Meta:
        unique_together = ('restaurant', 'user',)
```

This way the database will prevent duplicate records from being created.

After making this change, you can also use the built-in [`get_or_create`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/querysets/#get-or-create) function instead of checking for duplicates yourself:

```
liked_slot, created = LikedSlot.objects.get_or_create(restaurant=r, user=u)
```

Comment: I was just thinking of doing something like that. It's working perfectly, thanks!